# JQuery Mobile - change the taphold sensitivity

Tags: jquery, mobile

I have a problem with the JQuery mobile app I am developing on my Android.

Often when I mean to just scroll a list of items, the taphold even on the item I am touching is triggered.

That's very frustrating for my users.

What can I do about it?

Can I change the sensitivity of the taphold event?

Unfortunately I can't find anything on Google.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In jQuery-mobile 1.1.*, they have added more convenient ways to configure touch events: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html

For taphold, you can change the amount of time a tap should last before triggering the event by assigning a value to `$.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold`.

This value should be set in the mobileinit event, before importing JQM, but after importing jQuery. For instance, I did the following to avoid any overlap between the swipe and taphold events:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- JQM default options must be set after jQuery and before jQuery-mobile -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.event.special.tap.tapholdThreshold = 1000,
        $.event.special.swipe.durationThreshold = 999;
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the source: http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js

Look for the tap event (Starts at line 1049):

```
$.event.special.tap = {
```

At line 1090 to 1092:

```
timer = setTimeout(function() {
    triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "taphold", $.Event( "taphold" ) );
}, 750 );
```

Change the delay for the trigger of `taphold` event.

```
750ms = 0.75s
```

1000 is.....

```
1000 is equal to 1 second
```

**To comment**

Redefine the special tap event with new timer settings: chained from `750` to `1000`

This code can you put after your script inclusion af jQuery mobile (`<script src='jquery.mobile.js'></script>` and then `<script>$.event.special.tap = {...}</script>`)

```
$.event.special.tap = {
    setup: function() {
        var thisObject = this,
            $this = $( thisObject );

        $this.bind( "vmousedown", function( event ) {

            if ( event.which && event.which !== 1 ) {
                return false;
            }

            var origTarget = event.target,
                origEvent = event.originalEvent,
                timer;

            function clearTapTimer() {
                clearTimeout( timer );
            }

            function clearTapHandlers() {
                clearTapTimer();

                $this.unbind( "vclick", clickHandler )
                    .unbind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer )
                    .unbind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers );
            }

            function clickHandler(event) {
                clearTapHandlers();

                // ONLY trigger a 'tap' event if the start target is
                // the same as the stop target.
                if ( origTarget == event.target ) {
                    triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "tap", event );
                }
            }

            $this.bind( "vmousecancel", clearTapHandlers )
                .bind( "vmouseup", clearTapTimer )
                .bind( "vclick", clickHandler );

            timer = setTimeout(function() {
                    triggerCustomEvent( thisObject, "taphold", $.Event( "taphold" ) );
            }, 1000 ); // Changed from 750 to 1000
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: Great, thanks. Do you think that can be done without hacking the core?

Comment: The only way i can see is to take the whole event and redefine it.