# click event triggered after taphold

Tags: jquery, ios, jquery-mobile

I've been having a serious problem with handling the taphold event. Note that I only have this issue in IOS at the moment.

I have a jQuery Mobile application. In that application I have a list, when a taphold is invoked on one of those list items a modal popup is opened. The popup opens in the center of the window. When the user releases his finger from the screen a mouseup and mousedown (click) event is triggered on the element underneath the finger. When the popup is underneath the finger there is no issue. When the "modal" grey area is underneath the finger the popup immediately closes. This behavior is normal. What is not normal is the fact that these events are invoked. I could easily hack around it but it's not in my nature to do that. I'd like to know the cause.

I made a small fiddle to illustrate my issue but you need an iPad to test this. I was not able to reproduce the issue in an iPad emulator.

http://jsfiddle.net/yuFpa/38/

```
<code>
    <!DOCTYPE html> 

    <html>    
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-alpha.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-alpha.1.min.js"></script>
        </head> 

        <body> 
            <div data-role="page" id="one">        
                <div data-role="header">
                    <h1>Taphold dialog test</h1>
                </div>

                <div data-role="content">                
                    <ul data-role="listview">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dummy</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a id="taphold-popup-btn" href="#">Taphold me to open popup</a>
                        </li>

                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Dummy</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div data-role="popup" id="taphold-popup" data-overlay-theme="a">
                        <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>​
</code>
<code>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#taphold-popup-btn').bind('taphold', function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            e.preventDefault();        

            var $popup = $('#taphold-popup');
            $popup.popup();
            $popup.popup('open');
        });        
    });
</code>
```

Comment: try unbinding the click event `$('#taphold-popup-btn').unbind('click');`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293249/jquery-mobile-change-the-taphold-sensitivity , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502383/jquery-calling-click-event-after-taphold-event

Comment: Unbinding the event doesn't resolve the issue. I'd like to understand the problem so that I can fix it. I can easily fix it in a hackish but I rather not do that.