# How to get the duration of "taphold" when it is being executed in jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I want to be able to get the duration that the user has tapped and continuously held. Something like

```
$("div").bind("taphold", function(){
 if(this.duration > 500){
   //do something
 }
});
```

I can't find anything in the docs.

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293249/jquery-mobile-change-the-taphold-sensitivity) at all?

Comment: I found a different workaround, using a combination of vmousedown and setInterval